# Can you subtract time?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

After seeing a few redstone tutorials for a time-travelling machine, I thought of trying to reverse the time instead.

There's no such thing as a `/time subtract` or anything similar, and running `/time set 0` will only bring it to the start of the day in that corresponding Minecraft time tick.

So in any ways, how can I reverse time (at least ticks) in Bedrock Edition?

Comment: Most likley the tutorials are clickbait, and there is no real way to reverse time as that would require calculating things in reverse, which is quite hard.  The closest thing would be backups, but I dont think thats what you're after'

Comment: @valkyrie_pilot Yep, the only time travel really is `/time add` just adding up the current daytime. Also, backups? Not really, as it doesn't really count as a time travel thing (at least in my perspective).

Comment: Its definitely useful, however I cannot fairly give it an upvote as I dont play bedrock

Comment: you got a legit upvote, its not a bad question at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `/time add` with negative numbers:

```
time add -1000
```

Comment: Why didn't I realize this before? Negative `int`s is a great thing. Thanks for figuring it out.

Comment: Wait what?  This sets the time down, but it wont "reverse time" per se.  It will only turn the date back

Comment: @valkyrie_pilot It seems like that was all that the asker wanted, seeing that they accepted this...

Comment: @valkyrie_pilot Well, that's the point. The thing with these time travelling concepts in the videos doesn't revolve on the surrounding environment, but only changes the time of the game, making it seem like you are time travelling but you are not.